# Why Images.Media.insertImage doesn't require WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: android

I realize even I do not have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in my `AndroidManifest.xml

```
String path = Images.Media.insertImage(((Activity)MainView.this.getContext()).getContentResolver(), screenCaptureBitmap, "Title", "Description");
```

still able to write image file to location `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera`. May I know why is it so?

Comment: I don't have this issue on Samsung Galaxy S4 device - cannot perform `insertImage` without the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. Maybe you have a special case where the file you are trying to insert existed already (so no exception is thrown)?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

maybe in depend on the content provider `MediaStore`, you through it to insert, it's a RPC invoke. and the `MediaStore` provider in source code: `packages/providers/MediaProvider`, in it's manifest define the permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`,

may be it's the reason.